# Name of transformation $T(A)=A_L + A_R$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix. $A_L$ is an operator representing multiplication by this matrix $A$ on the left, and $A_R$ is multiplication on the right. Is there a name for the following transformation?
$$T(A)=A_L+A_R$$

A related operation $V(A)=A+A^T $ is called the "symmetrizer" in some books, so I'm wondering if $T$ also has a name.

In matrix form, this operator can be written as follows, with $\otimes$ a Kronecker product and $I$ the identity.

$$T(A)=A\otimes I + I\otimes A$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called the [anticommutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Ring_theory)

$$\{ A, B \} = AB + BA$$

(regarded as a function of $B$). The properties of this operation are abstracted by the theory of [Jordan algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_algebra).